# how to remove the quotations from the string in python?

Tags: python-3.x

the csv file returns the column value as dictionary format.but i cant get the value from dictionary by using dic.get("name") .it shows an error like ['str' object has no attribute 'get'].the actual problem is  csv return the dict with quates so the python consider this as string.how to remove the quates and how can i fix it. please help!!

```
with open('file.csv') as file:
  reader=csv.reader(file)
  count=0
  for idx,row in enumerate(reader):
   dic=row[5]
   if(idx==0):
     continue
   else:
     print(dic.get("name"))
```

```
filename    file_size   file_attributes region_count    region_id   region_shape_attributes region_attributes
adutta_swan.jpg -1  {"caption":"Swan in lake Geneve","public_domain":"no","image_url":"http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/images/swan.jpg"}   1   0   {"name":"rect","x":82,"y":105,"width":356,"height":207} {"name":"not_defined","type":"unknown","image_quality":{"good":true,"frontal":true,"good_illumination":true}}
wikimedia_death_of_socrates.jpg -1  {"caption":"The Death of Socrates by David","public_domain":"yes","image_url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Socrates#/media/File:David_-_The_Death_of_Socrates.jpg"}  3   0   {"name":"rect","x":174,"y":139,"width":108,"height":227}    {"name":"Plato","type":"human","image_quality":{"good_illumination":true}}
wikimedia_death_of_socrates.jpg -1  {"caption":"The Death of Socrates by David","public_domain":"yes","image_url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Socrates#/media/File:David_-_The_Death_of_Socrates.jpg"}  3   1   {"name":"rect","x":347,"y":114,"width":91,"height":209} {"name":"Socrates","type":"human","image_quality":{"frontal":true,"good_illumination":true}}
wikimedia_death_of_socrates.jpg -1  {"caption":"The Death of Socrates by David","public_domain":"yes","image_url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Socrates#/media/File:David_-_The_Death_of_Socrates.jpg"}  3   2   {"name":"ellipse","cx":316,"cy":180,"rx":17,"ry":12}    {"name":"Hemlock","type":"cup"}
```

Comment: You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader for this! Check my answer below!

Comment: it return the dict as string format '{"name":"data","x":82,"y":105,"width":356,"height":207}'.am cant get any data from the dictionary because it present within quatations is it any possible to remove the quatation.

Comment: 1. Open the csv file 2. Copy it's contents. 3. Edit the question and paste the csv there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`import csv
import ast
with open('file.csv') as file:
    #Read csv as dictreader
    reader=csv.DictReader(file)
    count=0
    #Iterate through rows
    for idx,row in enumerate(reader):
       #print(row)
       row_5=row['region_shape_attributes']
       y=ast.literal_eval(row_5)
       print(y.get("name"))`


this code also work to me
```

Comment: json library is built for the purpose of serialising and deserializing json files,you should not need ast for it. Also not sure why you unaccepted my answer, was there something not clear in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) which reads the csv as a dictionary!

```py
import csv
import json

with open('graph.csv') as file:
    #Read csv as dictreader
    reader=csv.DictReader(file)
    count=0
    #Iterate through rows
    for idx,row in enumerate(reader):
        #Load the string as a dictionary 
        region_shape_attributes = json.loads(row['region_shape_attributes'])
        print(region_shape_attributes['name'])
```

Comment: thanks.by use  DictReader now am again got the same error.`import csv

with open('file.csv') as file:
    #Read csv as dictreader
    reader=csv.DictReader(file)
    count=0
    #Iterate through rows
    for idx,row in enumerate(reader):
       #print(row)
       row_5=row['region_shape_attributes']
       print(row_5)
       print(row_5.get("name"))`  its give the result as ['str' object has no attribute 'get']

Comment: in csv file the 5th column contains the dictionary.i can get the dicttionary as string.so row_5.get("name") is not worked. i need to read the name filed in the dictionary.help!!

Comment: Can you update the question with how the csv looks like?

Comment: the dict contains {"name":"data","x":82,"y":105,"width":356,"height":207}  these attributes

Comment: Please update the csv in the question, atleast the first 10 rows, so that I can further help you!

Comment: I mean the content of the entire csv file! and not it's image